# Start kubernetes proxy in background and execute a command after (all in a one line command)

Tags: linux, kubernetes, command-line, background, kubectl

I would like to execute a `kubectl proxy` command in background and in the same terminal I want to run another command. According to the kuberentes docs, kubernetes proxy can be run in the background using `kubectl proxy &` , however for me doesnt work as I expect it.
For example, I want to run a kubernetes proxy and after exacute a curl command, all these in a single line of command:

```
kubectl proxy & bash -c "curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data-binary @something.json http://someip:someport/api/v1/namespaces/somenamespace/finalize"
```

In this version I was running the curl command in a subshell but this was not working. Also I have tried it without running in a subshell:

```
kubectl proxy & curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data-binary @something.json http://someip:someport/api/v1/namespaces/somenamespace/finalize
```

In both situations, it seems the command executed first after the proxy is started, which is obviously not right. I would appreciate any help/advice.

Here is a print screen:
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the command output as plain text?  It looks like you might have a shell-quoting problem more than a sequencing problem, at least at first; does removing the unnecessary `bash -c "..."` wrapper help at all?

Comment: (I know `kubectl port-forward` does not start instantly, so there is a potential sequencing problem too, and you need to remember to stop the proxy after the `curl` command finishes.  This is leaning a little more towards a shell script than a one-liner.)

Comment: @DavidMaze The point of the print screen is to see that curl executes before the proxy starts. I don't think that the text on the image can be used for anything, so I won't add to the question.

Comment: Its obvious as per the print screen shared by you that the proxy will execute first and then the curl command.You can refer to this [tutorial](https://humalect.com/blog/kubectl-proxy-command) by Rajesh Tilwani for kubectl proxy usage in detail.